# Would a bridge rectifier allow to detect µs-scale pulses of either polarity

Tags: signal, voltage-divider

The incoming signal is ground-referenced and consists of short (a few µs each) pulses at >150V. The signal is at ground potential the rest of the time (the "duty cycle" is low), and is of low impedance (< 100 ohms).

To adapt this signal to my 3.3V MCU, I've used a voltage divider + NPN like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv34Kh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This works fine, but assumes positive polarity on the signal. I need to make the circuit more flexible and accept negative signals as well - I want to get a logical 0 whenever the signal's absolute value is above some threshold (e.g. abs(V_signal) > 110±20V).

I'm thinking about using a diode bridge after the voltage divider, but I'm worried that the divider + the diodes' junction capacitance will form a low-pass filter, which in turn would attenuate the short signals too much. I'm not exactly sure how to compute how bad it would be though.
I can also place the bridge rectifier in front of the voltage divider, which isn't ideal (the bridge rectifier will need to be high voltage rated, up to 400V in this case). But this will likely work.
Maybe other approaches (that don't use a rectifier) are also possible.

How to approach this conversion? Are there any caveats?

Comment: Have you considered just using something akin to an NE-2 as the detector? (It works both ways and triggers at voltages that seem appropriate.)

Comment: If it is low impedance the. bridge capacitance of small signal diodes is <10 pF. I might be concerned about “probe R divider “ impedance mismatch with 10nH /cm wires. and compensate for this depending on interface cable. The result without proper impedances is ringing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bridge won't work for you because your input signal is ground referenced.

Consider mirroring  your circuit off the 3.3V rail with a PNP and then combining the two signals with a couple of gates.

Comment: OP could use 2 MPU pins to capture rising and falling edges. Just an idea...

Comment: I don't have a spare MCU pin, but I'll make my OR gate easily. Thanks!

Comment: Inverter + an OR or a NOR gate. Eg. 1/2 74HC4001